# Laravel dusk doesn't see vuejs selectors

Tags: laravel, testing, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-dusk

I am trying to run laravel dusk with vuejs and I got an error

**1) Tests\Browser\UserCreateTest::testAdminCanCreateAnotherUser
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\TimeOutException: Waited 5 seconds for selector [.users].**

This is my test

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $user = User::find(1);
            $browser
                ->loginAs($user)
                ->visit('/users');

            $browser->waitFor('.users');
```

In Vue template, I have div with class users.

Does anybody know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason of that exception was that I was using 'npm run hot' instead of 'npm run prod'

Answer (score 0):

To check if the element is on the page, you have to do this:

```
$browser->assertSee('Connection')
```

The *connection* is an example.

I also have difficulties to do dusk test. I can't press a button etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `dusk` attribute to your HTML element, for example:

```
<div class="users" dusk="user-list">
...
</div>
```

In your test, use the following:

```
$browser
    ->waitFor('@user-list');
```

> The dusk="" attribute works as a custom selector to be used by Laravel Dusk to interact with the HTML elements on the page.

Reference:
[Testing Vue components with Laravel Dusk](https://laravel-news.com/testing-vue-components-with-laravel-dusk)

Answer (score -1):

That's just how `waitFor` method works.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk#waiting-for-elements):

> The `waitFor` method may be used to pause the execution of the test until the element matching the given CSS selector is displayed on the page. By default, this will pause the test for a maximum of five seconds before throwing an exception.

So, it waits for `.users` to appear for 5 seconds and then throws an exception.

Comment: I understand it, but why div with class users isn't present in the test? And why the test fails?

Comment: @ArtemPetrusenko Dusk doesn't see any element with class `users` on given page. He waits for it for 5 seconds and then throws an exception. That's why the test fails.

Comment: But as you can see this selector is present on the page.  https://clip2net.com/s/3QNqWd2

Comment: Apparently, the element is not there for some reason when Dusk is running.

Comment: How can we check it?